# Publishing GulpJs minified/concatenated javascript via MSDeploy and Teamcity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msdeploy, bundling-and-minification

Apologies if this question has been asked before. I have found variants on this theme but nothing that seems to fit our particular configuration.

We have developed a custom GulpJS task which parses a .json file located inside our folder assets/javascript. This json file contains an array of relative paths to javascript files (both our own and library) in a specific order for minification. They are then outputted to the folder assets/javascript/build and concatenated. The javascript source files are in the project but the minified and concatenated versions of the scripts, in fact the entire build folder itself, are not included in the Visual Studio project.

Ideally, I would like to have a step in the MSDeploy configuration which would copy all the files in the javascript build folder to the destination. Otherwise I could potentially include another step in Teamcity to do so.

Has anyone successfully instituted a similar build configuration and could share some insight? I tried using the MSBuild copy task but that didn't seem to copy the files to the output location. One option that I am considering is including the minified scripts in the project file but this might potentially trip up other developers who don't have Gulp running in their development environments (hilarious as that might be)